# How can i replicate my ami from one account to other account through script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How can I replicate my Amazon AMI from one account to another account through the script can anyone help how to do so.

Comment: [See the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/sharingamis-explicit.html)

Comment: Do you want to _copy_ an AMI to another account, or is it sufficient to grant the other account access to _use_ the AMI?

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for your reply

Comment: Actually i want to copy an AMI from Account A to Account B wherein i should be able to launch a new instance using that AMI